# Gradle does not see a plugin that is on the plugin portal

Tags: gradle, markdown, gradle-plugin

Gradle 4.6 here. Trying to use [markdown-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/aalmiray/markdown-gradle-plugin) to convert markdown files into HTML as part of my build. My `build.gradle` specifies:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.4'
    id 'java'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.6'
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.markdown' version '2.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
        ... (all of my dependencies here)
    )
}

... rest of my build.gradle here
```

When I run:

```
./gradlew clean markdownToHtml
```

I get:

```
$ ./gradlew clean markdownToHtml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.kordamp.gradle.markdown', version: '2.0.0']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.kordamp.gradle.markdown']
   > Could not find method register() for arguments [markdownToHtml, class org.kordamp.gradle.plugin.markdown.tasks.MarkdownToHtmlTask, org.kordamp.gradle.plugin.markdown.MarkdownPlugin$1@3b46a8ba] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I can verify that I *do* see the 2.0.0 version of the plugin on the [Gradle plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.kordamp.gradle.markdown).

**Can anybody spot where I'm going awry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the kordmap plugins [website](https://aalmiray.github.io/kordamp-gradle-plugins/#_requirements):

> Java 8 and Gradle 5 are the minimum requirements to use any of these
>   plugins.

So your version of gradle needs an upgrade.

---

The error is coming from when the plugin attempts to [use](https://github.com/aalmiray/markdown-gradle-plugin/blob/10331e035b2764fc7b5ca3166edc7f3e7360d134/src/main/groovy/org/kordamp/gradle/plugin/markdown/MarkdownPlugin.groovy#L35) [`TaskContainer::register`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#register-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-org.gradle.api.Action-), which was introduced in gradle 4.9, so you might be safe to upgrade to version 4.9, but I'd suggest going with what the website says and bumping it to version 5.